# Matching parts of URIs with Regular Expressions

Tags: php, regex, uri

I want to match this url /Real_estate_Listing_Detail.asp?PropID=245  with the ability to EXCEPT PropID numbers...

In other words,

Match /Real_estate_Listing_Detail.asp?PropID=ANY NUMBER HERE, except, 286,289,290,180

Thanks in advance... this shouldnt be as hard as I make it...

This is for a wordpress plugin, so a single line experssion is needed.

Comment: What language do you need this for?

Comment: Added PHP tag since you said you're using Wordpress.

Answer (score 2):

If the language you are using supports [look-around assertions](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html), you could use this:

```
^/Real_estate_Listing_Detail\.asp\?PropID=(?!(?:286|289|290|180)$)\d+$
^/Real_estate_Listing_Detail\.asp\?PropID=\d+(?<!=(?:286|289|290|180))$
```

The first is a look-ahead assertion and the second a look-behind assertion.

Otherwise use two expressions: one to match the pattern and one to exclude the specific values:

```
^/Real_estate_Listing_Detail\.asp\?PropID=\d+$
^/Real_estate_Listing_Detail\.asp\?PropID=(286|289|290|180)$
```

So the first expression must match while the second must not match.

Comment: In the first case, that would fail to match "...PropID=3180" or "...PropID=51289" etc.

Comment: The problem is I am using a wordpress plugin and can only use single line expressions...  any help?

Comment: PCRE (used by PHP) supports look-around assertions. So you can use one of the former regular expressions.